# Why is the assignment wrong?

Tags: python

```
def foo(a, b):
    a = 1
    b[0] = 2

p, q = 100, [200, 300]
foo(p, q)
print(p, q)

>>> 100 [2, 300]
```

My question is that, why q changes, but p does not? Thank you!

Comment: Did you expect `b` to be copied? It's not, all names are references. See the duplicate on how this works. Or see [How to clone or copy a list?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2612802) to create a copy.

Comment: Before putting your questions here, please search for the similar. There are too many similar questions, you can have answers from them

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried searching but used the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 1):

q is a list therefore is "passed by reference" to the function. p is passed by value.

Comment: As a token of appreciation please upvote the answer when you find it helpful.